# Calling C functions from Fortran

Tags: c, fortran

I'm trying to call C functions using Fortran. So first  was trying to simply call a non parametrized, void function via Fortran.

Kindly help me resolve the following errors in the given code.

C Code for matrix multiplication:

```
#include <stdio.h>


extern "C" 

{ void __stdcall mat();
}


void mat()
{
 int m, n, p, q, c, d, k, sum = 0;

  printf("Enter the number of rows and columns of first matrix\n");
 scanf("%d%d", &m, &n);

  int first[m][n];

  printf("Enter the elements of first matrix\n");

  for (  c = 0 ; c < m ; c++ )
   for ( d = 0 ; d < n ; d++ )
  scanf("%d", &first[c][d]);

  printf("Enter the number of rows and columns of second matrix\n");
  scanf("%d%d", &p, &q);

  int second[p][q];

 if ( n != p )
   printf("Matrices with entered orders can't be multiplied with each other.\n");
 else
 {
  printf("Enter the elements of second matrix\n");

  for ( c = 0 ; c < p ; c++ )
   for ( d = 0 ; d < q ; d++ )
     scanf("%d", &second[c][d]);

  int multiply[m][q];  

  for ( c = 0 ; c < m ; c++ )
 {
   for ( d = 0 ; d < q ; d++ )
   {
    for ( k = 0 ; k < p ; k++ )
    {
      sum = sum + first[c][k]*second[k][d];
    }

    multiply[c][d] = sum;
    sum = 0;
  }
}

   printf("Product of entered matrices:-\n");

  for ( c = 0 ; c < m ; c++ )
  {
    for ( d = 0 ; d < q ; d++ )
      printf("%d\t", multiply[c][d]);

    printf("\n");
  }
 }

 }

  int main()
{
 mat();
return 0;
 }
```

Also, the code for calling the function mat from Fortran that I wrote is :

```fortran
      program mat_mult  !This is a main program.
      
      call mat()
      stop
      end
```

On executing the C file I get the following error:

```
matrix_mult.c:5: error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before string constant
```

On compiling the Fortran file, I get the following error:

```
/tmp/ccQAveKc.o: In function `MAIN__':
matrix_mult.f:(.text+0x19): undefined reference to `mat_'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Answer (score 1):

A few things first

1. I'm assuming you're using a C99 compiler because the C code you've written will not work on a C89 compiler.
2. extern "C" is for C++ programs: not C programs.

Not really sure which compiler you're using.  Just assuming you're using gcc and gfortran since it looks like you're on a Linux based system.

gcc just adds a leading _ to the symbols: so mat becomes _mat.
gfortran adds both a leading and trailing _ to the symbols: so mat becomes _mat_.

To make C and Fortran talk

a) Remove the main function from the C code

b) Remove extern "C" declaration.  This is a C++ declaration that tells the compiler that the routine mat should not have any name mangling.

c) Since you don't have any parameters, just assume __cdecl and change void mat() to void mat_().  If you have to use stdcall, then you need to compile with --enable-stdcall-fixup.  stdcall will be needed if the Fortran program has to pass parameters to the C program but that is a different ball game.  Instead of _mat_, the compiler generates mat@0

d) Your C routine will now look like

```
#include <stdio.h>
void mat_()
{
    ...
}

/* No main */
```

e) Since the routine mat is not declared in the Fortran code, the compiler needs to know that it is external.

```
program mat_mult
external mat
call mat()
stop
end
```

f) Compile and link (say the C program is called mat.c and the fortran program is called matmul.f)

```
gcc -g -c mat.c
gfortran -g matmul.f mat.o -o matmul
```

There will probably be a whole load of comments recommending that you use F2003 or F2008 but if you have been told that you have to use F77, then you have to use F77.